# Генерация больших целых значений

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Как сгенерировать значения, допустим от 10000 до 99999? Используя `Math.random()` проскакивают четырех-,шести- значные.

Comment: +1 за слово "целочисельных"

Comment: спасибо кста)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(long)(Math.random() * (99999 - 10000) + 10000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще один вариант. Генерация и вывод 100 чисел:

```
new Random().ints(100, 10_000, 100_000).forEach(System.out::println);
```

или аналог:

```
new Random().ints(10_000, 100_000).limit(100).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Нижняя граница (10000) включает значение, верхняя (100000) - нет.

Answer (score -1):

```
Random random = new Random();
int num = random.nextInt(900000) + 100000;
```

или

```
Random random = new SecureRandom();
int num = random.nextInt(900000) + 100000;
```